# Can't empty rubbish bin

Tags: 13.10, trash, bleachbit

So, I had issues having a full disk, but for now I solved it.
Now, after I installed Bleachbit, this program was Wipping free disk space and all of suddenly it freezes. I left it like 30min but as it was still frozen I decide to reboot the notebook and do it again, same thing happens, so I decide to leave it cause the full disk sign didn't appear.
BUT
I noticed that I have a folder in the rubbish bin named "ablyZTulPm.2.2" and every time that I delete it from the rubbish bin, the ubuntu "explorer,exe" it freezes.
I looked up here some other similar questions, I went to `~/.local/share/Trash/` and try to manually delete what was inside of the folders, but every time that I do it, the folder regenerates again.
I tried with Bleachbit to empty the rubbish bin and Bleachbit stopped working.
I tried to run this at the terminal

```
sudo -i
rm -rv /home/<your_username>/.local/share/Trash/files/*
```

But the terminal keeps delete the folder as the folder regenerates it self.

So..what can I do?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete also all the metadata associated with the Trash, not just the files.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```

No need to use `sudo` for anything here. The files are yours.

The next time you send something to the trash, the Trash folder will be regenerated properly.

Comment: Great, that work, but I used "-rv" instead of "-rf" and "/home/user" instead of "~" don't know what's the difference, but it worked. 
Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. The modifier `v` just prints what's being deleted. The modifier `f` don't ask questions or print errors, if any. It's the same, on the bottom. On bash, `~` or `$HOME` equals your home directory, and can be used to generalize any command, so I don't need to know where your home directory is. Try using `~` instead of the path to your home directory on your commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had a directory that was a copy of the directory that was it's parent. I don't remember how I got that situation. I had to do a `chmod -Rf a+w` on this directory before I could do a `rm -Rf` on it. It seemed to have to do with one of the three special permission bits. `ls -l` does not show them but it did show a green bar over the directory name.

Comment: I was confused before the "green bar over the directory name" at which point I was totally lost.